# dplyr arrange data frame based on column position with new R pipe |>

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to sort my data frame based on a column that I pass to dplyr's `arrange` function with its position. This works as long as I'm using the "old" tidyverse/magrittr pipe operator. However, changing it to the new R pipe returns an error:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 4, 1, 5),
                 y = 1:4)

# Works
df %>% 
  arrange(.[1])

  x y
1 1 3
2 3 1
3 4 2
4 5 4
```

```
# Throws error
df |> 
  arrange(.[1])

Error:
! arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
Problem with `mutate()` column `..1`.
i `..1 = .[1]`.
x object '.' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I still arrange by column position when using the new R pipe?

I realize that the |> operator does not accept the "." as an argument, but I still don't know how else I could address the data then.

Update:

This seems to work, but wondering if there is something more straightforward:

```
df |> 
  arrange(cur_data() |> select(1))
```

Comment: The base pipe `|>` is not (yet) as flexible as the magrittr pipe `%>%`.  In particular with `%>%` you use a dot to represent what’s being piped. With `|>` there is no character to represent what is being piped. See e.g. [this article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3621369/use-the-new-r-pipe-built-into-r-41.html).

Comment: I know, that's why I'm trying to figure out how I could specify what's piped.

Comment: As far as I know so far there are only *work-around* solutions. That's why for now I stick with `%>%`

Comment: So, bottomline, as long as the new pipe operator doesn't have its own way of piping the first argument, this is gonna be a pain.

Comment: Maybe your workaround is just `arrange(cur_data()[[1]])`?

Comment: Yes, something with cur_data it is probably (e.g. similar to my workaround with `select(1)` shown above). Does anyone know if and when they will implement a pipe-first-argument thing to |>?

Comment: I'm not sure that your diagnosis is entirely accurate. Note that `df |> arrange(.data[["x"]])` works, with `.data` referencing the first argument (passed by the pipe) to `arrange()`. `df |> arrange(.data[[1]])` fails, I guess because of a design decision not to support numerical subsetting in the tidyverse. So really I think the tidyverse is trying to tell you not to rely on column order... `c1name <- names(df)[[1]]; ...; df |> arrange(.data[[c1name]])`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a lambda function (suggestion by @Martin Morgan in the comments to specify the columns position instead of names):

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 4, 1, 5),
                 y = 1:4)

df |> 
  (\(z) arrange(z, z[[1]]))()

#   x y
# 1 1 3
# 2 3 1
# 3 4 2
# 4 5 4
```

With `order`, this looks okay:

```r
df |>
  (\(z) z[order(z[,1]), ])()

  x y
3 1 3
1 3 1
2 4 2
4 5 4
```

Comment: I can't specify the column names. It's part of a larger workflow/loop with everchanging column names. The only constant thing is the column position, hence I need to specify the column position.

Comment: Use column position in the anonymous function `df |> (\(z) arrange(z, z[[1]]))()` ?

Comment: That looks like it's working indeed.

Comment: Yes, I had something in mind with anonymous functions as well, but couldn't figure it out. Happy to accept is as an answer of you create one.

Comment: There's something unexpected though when the anonymous function happens to use the name of the column, e.g., `(\(x) arrange(x, x[[1]]))()`!

Comment: yes, so would probably need to use something unique like zzzzz. However, in my real-life case I do at least know that the column name will never be "x", so should be safe to use this.

Answer (score 1):

|> does not support dot but tidyverse functions do support cur_data().

```
# 1
df |> arrange(cur_data()[1])
```

Another possibility is the Bizarro pipe which is not really a pipe but does look like one and uses only base R.

```
# 2
df ->.; arrange(., .[1])
```

or any of these work-arounds

```
# 3
arrange1 <- function(.) arrange(., .[1])
df |> arrange1()

# 4
df |> (function(.) arrange(., .[1]))()

# 5
df |> list() |> setNames(".") |> with(arrange(., .[1]))

# 6
with. <- function(data, expr, ...) {
  eval(substitute(expr), list(. = data), enclos = parent.frame())
}    
df |> with.(arrange(., .[1]))

# these hard code variable names so are not directly comparable
# but can be used if that is ok

# 7
df |> arrange(x)

# 8
df |> with(arrange(data.frame(x, y), x))
```

Comment: Thanks for this list of options. Interesting to see in how many different way a pipe could be done.

Comment: I also saw some sort of discussion from you in the r developers group about this `|> . =>` usage, because that's exactly the error I'm getting if I try `df |> . =>
  arrange(.[1])` after enabling it in the sys environment: Error in arrange(.[1]) : 
  pipe placeholder must only appear as a top-level argument in the RHS call. Is there any place where I can keep myself updated on the development around the new pipe operator and potential fixes?

Comment: Typing `news()` into the R console will display new features in the version of R you are using.  This link will display new features in the development version of R: https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS